# click signal in QTableView which is view of QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5

I need a `QListView` with buttons for a `QComboBox`, but since writing delegates is a huge pain. I opted for a `QTableView` instead since there will be always the same buttons for each line. My only problem is that I can't seem to catch the `clicked` signal from within the `QComboBox`.

I attached a mwe to illustrate what I mean:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QModelIndex, Qt, QAbstractTableModel, QVariant
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QComboBox, QTableView, QWidget, QVBoxLayout


class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            col = index.column()
            if col == 0:
                return str(index.row())
            elif col == 1:
                return '✎'
            elif col == 2:
                return '✘'
        return QVariant()

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 3

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 5


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    model = Model()

    main = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(main)

    view = QTableView()
    view.clicked.connect(lambda _: print('Click Table'))  # Works fine
    view.setModel(model)
    layout.addWidget(view)

    combo = QComboBox()
    combo.setModel(model)
    combo.setView(QTableView())
    combo.view().clicked.connect(lambda _: print('Click Combo'))  # Does'nt show
    layout.addWidget(combo)

    main.resize(500, 300)
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following signal to trigger a click in the combobox :

```
view = QTableView()
view.clicked.connect(lambda: print('Click Table'))  # Works fine
view.setModel(model)
layout.addWidget(view)

combo = QComboBox()
combo.setModel(Model())
combo.setView(QTableView())

combo.activated.connect(lambda: print('Click Combo'))  # Works fine too
layout.addWidget(combo)
```

Or if you need to detect only when a click or a keyboard input changes the selected item :

```
combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda: print('Click Combo'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That seems to be right direction. How do I get the index of the the click? `combo.activated.connect(lambda ind: print(f'Click Combo {ind}'))` only gives me the row but not the column.

Answer (score 2):

I found a non-elegant way to achieve this by using the `mousePressEvent` of the view and the `combo.activated` signal (Thanks PRMoureu). I post it in case anybody can use it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PyQt5.QtCore import QModelIndex, Qt, QAbstractTableModel, QVariant
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QComboBox, QTableView, QWidget, QVBoxLayout


class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    DATA = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            col = index.column()
            if col == 0:
                return self.DATA[index.row()]
            elif col == 1:
                return '✎'
            elif col == 2:
                return '✘'
        return QVariant()

    def callback(self, row, col):
        print(f'Clicked {row}:{col}')

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 3

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 5


class Table(QTableView):
    BUTTON_SIZE = 20
    click_col_index = 0

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.verticalHeader().hide()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)

        self.setColumnWidth(0, self.width() - 2 * self.BUTTON_SIZE)
        self.setColumnWidth(1, self.BUTTON_SIZE)
        self.setColumnWidth(2, self.BUTTON_SIZE)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        x = event.localPos().x()
        width = self.columnWidth(0)
        self.click_col_index = max([0, (x - width + self.BUTTON_SIZE) // self.BUTTON_SIZE])


class SignalMixer:
    def __init__(self, model, view, combo):
        self.model = model
        self.view = view
        self.combo = combo

        self.combo.activated.connect(self.clicked)

    def clicked(self, row):
        if self.view.click_col_index:
            self.model.callback(row, self.view.click_col_index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    model = Model()

    main = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(main)

    view = QTableView()
    view.clicked.connect(lambda _: print('Click Table'))
    view.setModel(model)
    layout.addWidget(view)

    combo = QComboBox()
    combo.setModel(model)
    combo.setView(Table())
    layout.addWidget(combo)

    mixer = SignalMixer(model, combo.view(), combo)

    main.resize(500, 300)
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```